# Does it necessary to put original credentials to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken after successful authentication in AuthenticationProvider?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I receive a already confirmed user id at the entrance. I decided to write my implementation of `Authentication` for incoming id - `VkIdAuthentication`. And implementation of `AuthenticationProvider` that receiving `VkIdAuthentication` then find the `UserDetails` and returns `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`.

But i haven't got original credentials the user supplied. Is it ok to put null as credentials for `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`?

One comment in [`AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java#L219) confuse me:

> // Ensure we return the original credentials the user supplied,
>           // so subsequent attempts are successful even with encoded passwords.

Comment: AFAIK it is OK to pass null, empty or whatever value if you can ensure that the user is himself (using a Bearer Token for example), this way you do not have necessarily the user credentials, but you can confirm his identity.

Comment: @nullptr does it make sense to return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken from my AuthenticationProvider? And is it normal that AuthenticationProvider receive one type `Authentication` - `VkIdAuthentication` and return another `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the following comment found at [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/1616):

> More broadly: perhaps there are auth providers that do require
>   credentials even after a session has been authenticated, or perhaps
>   there are other use cases where having credentials around is necessary
>   for some other purpose, but (from my naive perspective) it seems that
>   user credentials are never needed after authentication has been
>   completed successfully, so perhaps all authentication managers should
>   clear credentials from Authentication instances, regardless of the
>   type of token/provider involved?

And from what I see in the [current source codes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/af3c6d49728fc3b2270a07ce09827fb1e4890c6d/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/ProviderManager.java#L218) , the default behaviour is that even you return an `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` from `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` it will then call `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken#eraseCredentials()` very soon to set the credentials to NULL again.

So I would say it is rather safe to return Authentication with NULL credentials if you do not require to use user credentials after successful authentication.